# sudo permission denied in SSH terminal

Tags: python, shell, sudo

I Have a Django Project and have uploaded in cPanel via FileZilla . I want to instlall Django and PIP via SSH terminal . I am getting an error "bash: /bin/su: Permission denied"

```
(MyDjangoEnv) epaysave@epaysave.com [~/public_html/epaysave.com/epaysave/epaysave_stageone]# sudo yum install python-pip
[sudo] password for epaysave:
epaysave is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

(MyDjangoEnv) epaysave@epaysave.com [~/public_html/epaysave.com/epaysave/epaysave_stageone]# su epaysave
bash: /bin/su: Permission denied
```

Comment: Your error is there and is pretty straightforward: `epaysave is not in the sudoers file`. It's not a problem with python, it's not a problem with ssh, it's a problem (or rather: a feature) in your linux configuration.

Comment: Contact your admin and ask him for admin access else sudo won't work.